# Time Format error

Tags: java, android

> 10-27 06:58:39.781:  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" at offset 0
>   (at offset 0)

I am getting this exception at runtime.I am not sure about the timing format.But I am expected the timing like this `12:23am`.

**Time.java:**

```
private void setTime(int iETextID) {
        try {
            etTimePicker = (EditText) findViewById(iETextID);
            String strTime = etTimePicker.getText().toString();
            final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",
                    Locale.getDefault());
            mcurrentTime.setTime(formatter.parse(strTime));
```

Comment: What is the output of etTimePicker.getText().toString() ?

Comment: @Outlaw I need to get like this 12:23am while retrieve the value from json-php

Comment: @Richard you should add some debug statements, test if the etTimePicker.getText().toString() is empty or not. something like System.out.println("etTimePicker = " + etTimePicker.getText().toString()), but in an android debuglog type of way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unparseable date: ""
```

`""` is not a valid date. That is the issue here.

Make sure `strTime` can parse with this formatter.

Eg:

```
String strTime = "10:12 AM";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",
            Locale.getDefault());
Date date=formatter.parse(strTime); // get the date
System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); // change the formate
```

Out put:

```
10:12 AM
```

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: @HareshChhelana not really. To be an answer length of the answer is doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

`hh:mm aa` is a valid format. The problem here is that the EditText is empty, you're trying to parse an empty string.

```
String strTime = etTimePicker.getText().toString(); // strTime is ""
```